# Shiny: Reactive sliderInput not working :(

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making an R Shiny app where the graph type switches between line and stacked area. I want to have a slider which fliters the input data by y-axis values. When the graph type is stacked, the maximum y-axis value is obviously a lot higher than for a line graph. How do I update the maximum value for the slider when the graph type changes? As shown in the code below, I'm trying to use observeEvent, but this isn't having the desired effect. Any help would be greatly appreciated (I acknowledge that plotly could handle some of this but in general, I don't like the package).

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# simulate some grouped data
mydata=bind_rows(lapply(LETTERS[1:5],function(x){
  as_tibble(data.frame(xvals=seq(1,100,1))) %>% 
    mutate(grp=x) })) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(yvals=runif(1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  arrange(xvals) %>% 
  mutate(yvals=cumsum(yvals)) %>% 
  ungroup()


ui=fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dev reactive yaxis"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons('graphType',"",c("line","stacked"),"line"),
      uiOutput("ylimits")),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("myplot"))))


server=function(input,output,session) {

  ## y slider
  output$ylimits=renderUI({
    # req(ymax())
    req(input$graphType)
    if(input$graphType=="line"){
      ymax=max(mydata$yvals,na.rm=T)
    } else{
      temp=mydata %>% 
        filter(yvals==max(yvals,na.rm=T))
      ymax=sum(temp$yvals,na.rm=T)
    }
    
    sliderInput('yslider','',min=0,max=ymax,value=c(0,ymax))
  })
  
  ## update slider when graph type changes. This doesn't seem to work :(
  observeEvent(input$graphType=="stacked",{
    # rv$ymax<-funGety
    
    ## get max value for yaxis
     if(input$graphType=="line"){
      ymax=max(mydata$yvals,na.rm=T)
    } else{
      temp=mydata %>% 
        filter(yvals==max(yvals,na.rm=T))
      ymax=sum(temp$yvals,na.rm=T)
    }
    updateSliderInput(session=session,'yslider','',min=0,max=ymax,value=c(0,ymax))
  })
  
  
  ## plot data
  pdat=reactive({
    req(input$yslider)
    mydata %>% 
      filter(yvals>input$yslider[1]&yvals<input$yslider[2])
  })
  
  ## make plot
  myplot=reactive({
    req(pdat())
    req(input$graphType)
    ggplot(pdat(),aes(xvals,yvals))+
      { if (input$graphType=="line") geom_line(aes(colour=grp)) else geom_area(aes(fill=grp)) }
  })
  
  ## render plot
  output$myplot=renderPlot({
    req(myplot())
    myplot()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: When the graph is stacked, you want the slider bar to be what, like the ~239 of each of them stacked? If that's the case, the issue I see is none of the yvals from each group will be in the 200's, they will still max in the 50s. Meaning if the slider bar was at 100, 150, or 200, nothing would filter out, until you drop below 50, where it will begin to filter.

Comment: If you did want it to filter at the ~239 or so, then your code is really close already. The observeEvent would be unneeded, all you would need to do is change the "else" of the ylimits renderUI to ```temp=mydata %>% 
        group_by(grp)%>%
        filter(yvals==max(yvals,na.rm=T))``` This way it would sum up each of the groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to filter the stacked chart based on the sum of the observations per "xvals":

```
mydata %>% group_by(xvals) %>% summarize(total_yvals = sum(yvals,na.rm=T))
```

It is this sum per xvals that should be searched for by max() to get the max value for the slider, and it should be this sum per xvals that should be filtered in the data.frame.

This code works for me:

```html
server=function(input,output,session) {
  
  ## y slider
  output$ylimits=renderUI({
    # req(ymax())
    req(input$graphType)
    if(input$graphType=="line"){
      ymax=max(mydata$yvals,na.rm=T)
    } else{
      # get the max value out of the summed up entries on each xvals
      ymax = mydata %>% group_by(xvals) %>% summarize(yvals = sum(yvals,na.rm=T)) %>% pull(yvals) %>% max()
    }
    
    sliderInput('yslider','',min=0,max=ymax,value=c(0,ymax))
  })
  

  ## plot data
  pdat=reactive({
    req(input$yslider,input$graphType)
    
    # join the sum of the stacked areas to allow for filtering
    mydata <- mydata %>% left_join(
      mydata %>% group_by(xvals) %>% summarize(total_yvals = sum(yvals,na.rm=T)),
      by = "xvals"
    ) %>% as.data.frame()
    
    # depending on the selection filter either individual observations or the sum of the stacked areas
    if(input$graphType == "line"){
      mydata <- mydata %>% 
        filter(yvals>input$yslider[1]&yvals<input$yslider[2])
    } else{
      mydata <- mydata %>% 
        filter(total_yvals>input$yslider[1]&total_yvals<input$yslider[2])
    }
    
    return(mydata)
  })
  
  ## render plot
  output$myplot=renderPlot({
    req(pdat(),input$graphType,input$yslider)
    
    p <- ggplot(pdat(),aes(xvals,yvals))+
      { if (input$graphType=="line") geom_line(aes(colour=grp)) else geom_area(aes(fill=grp)) }
    
    return(p)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks ouflak :)